# does magnolia implement struts? and If i have something with struts its easy to integrate?

Tags: struts, magnolia

I am very new in magnolia and I still have some difficults getting the idea to develop components, but my problem is that after read the docs offered in the site (I wonder if there are other kind of docs, as only for developers) I still dont get if they use Struts or not, at first I thought so, but I am not sure at all, could somebody tell me this? Just to know be clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing resembling a Struts 1 or Struts 2 signature anywhere in any of the Magnolia artifacts. I'm not sure what made you think it used Struts, and downloading their CE it was a simple matter of looking at the deployed jars to see that it didn't.

I also checked a couple of the Magnolia libraries to see if there were shaded versions and I saw nothing of note. While I didn't spend much time on this (~five minutes) there's nothing obviously Struts-ish.

Comment: thank you, neither I found it, but someone told me it uses (my boss) and I wanted to be sure,I found out with liferay they use many struts... but not in magnolia. thank you anyways.